# Least Square Approximation Using Legendre Polynomials

Tags: definite-integrals, absolute-value, approximation-theory

Obtain a fourth degree least squares polynomial for $f(x) = 1/|x|$ over $[-1,1]$ by means of Legendre Polynomials

I got stuck when trying the integral over the given interval.

Is there another way of solving this?

Comment: Do you mind showing what integral you have problem with?

Comment: @mickep this is the integral (don't know if that's the right path to take): $$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{|x|}dx$$

Comment: That sure diverges. Please show your work, even just using the formal steps using the Legendre polynomials. It might be that the process does not lead to an answer.

Comment: First, I calculated the coefficients of the legendre polynomial required to minimise the error of the polynomial used to approximate the function: $$a_r=\frac{2r+1}{2}\int_{-1}^1f(x)P_r(x)dx$$

Comment: Thus $$a_0=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{|x|}P_0 (x)dx$$ Where P is the Legendre Polynomial and $$P_0=1$$ This gives $$a_0=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{|x|}.dx$$ This is now where the problem is.  @mickep